# Symfony CollectionType with "allow_add" not adding child entity to parent entity

Tags: forms, collections, doctrine-orm, symfony

On Symfony 2.8, I got the following entities:

Contact:

```
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EmailContact", mappedBy="contact", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    protected $emails;

    // ...

    /**
     * Add emails
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\EmailContact $emails
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function addEmail(\AppBundle\Entity\EmailContact $emails)
    {
        $this->emails[] = $emails;
        $emails->setContact($this);  //this line added by me

        return $this;
    }

    // ...
```

EmailContact:

```
class EmailContact
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contact", inversedBy="emails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $contact;

    // ...
```

The rest of the methods were automatically generated by the `doctrine:generate:entities` command.

My forms are as follows:

ContactType:

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{   
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', null, [
                'label' => 'contact.name',
            ])
            ->add('emails', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
                'entry_type' => EmailContactType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Contact'
        ]);
    }
```

EmailContactType:

```
class EmailContactType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => 'emailContact.email',
            ])                
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\EmailContact'
        ]);
    }
```

I do the javascript to add extra fields to the request, and submit it. Example request (from Symfony Profiler):

```
[ 
name => test4,
emails => [ 
    0 => [ 
        email => t@t.t4
    ], 
    1 => [ 
        email => t@t.t5
    ] 
], 
_token => ...
]
```

But I get the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO email_contact ...

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'contact_id' cannot be null
```

Debugging, I see that the `addEmail` method above never gets called. What is happening here?

Comment: You don't have correctly mapped relationship, for example `@JoinColumn` annotation on attribute `$contact` in `EmailContact` entity. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata

Comment: Also, since you have problem with basic mappings, first i would make sure basic inserts of entities is working, and only then try to make `allow_add` form work.

Comment: also, make sure you also have `removeEmail` method in `Contact` entity, as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Comment: any help for this? :S
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164731/embed-from-symfony-null-when-allow-add-is-true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed `by_reference => false` in form collection definition

```
->add('emails', CollectionType::class, [
    'label' => false,
    'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
    'entry_type' => EmailContactType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'delete_empty' => true,
    'prototype' => true,
    'by_reference' => false; // <--- you missed this
]);
```

Take a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference)

Your code should run as expected after this modification.

Moreover remember that if you have a `setEmails()` method inside `Contact` class, the framework end up to calling it and so you need (for each element of the collection) to set contact as well (as you're correctly doing in `addEmails()`)